How to buffering RTSP live data?
I am trying to play live RTSP data on QNX Neutrino OS. I have created C code to do this and it works. I have connected my development kit and PC via ethernet. I can play RTSP video streamed from PC on my development kit but the first image is always distorted. The video is distorted for about 3-4 seconds on the screen.
My stream code in PC:
cvlc -vvv ~/Videos/bbb_sunflower_1080p_60fps_normal.mp4 --sout '#transcode{acodec=mp4a}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/stream}' :network-caching=1500

My C code in Development Kit(Plays video during 60 sec.):
#include <screen/screen.h>
#include <mm/renderer.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define WINGRP_NAME_MAX_LEN 128

// I/O devices
static const char *video_device_url    = "screen:?winid=videosamplewindowgroup&wingrp=videosamplewindowgroup";
static const char *audio_device_url    = "audio:default";

// Name of video context
static const char *video_context_name = "samplevideocontextname";

// Window group name
static const char *window_group_name = "videosamplewindowgroup";

// Window Name
const char *window_name = "appwindow";

strm_dict_t* calculate_rect(int width, int height) {
    const int image_width = 640;
    const int image_height = 480;
    const float image_aspect = (float)image_width / (float)image_height;
    const float aspect_tolerance = 0.1;

    char buffer[16];
    strm_dict_t *dict = strm_dict_new();

    if (NULL == dict) {
        return NULL;
    }

    //fullscreen is the default.
    dict = strm_dict_set(dict, "video_dest_x", "0");
    if (NULL == dict)
        goto fail;
    dict = strm_dict_set(dict, "video_dest_y", "0");
    if (NULL == dict)
        goto fail;
    dict = strm_dict_set(dict, "video_dest_w", itoa(width, buffer, 10));
    if (NULL == dict)
        goto fail;
    dict = strm_dict_set(dict, "video_dest_h", itoa(height, buffer, 10));
    if (NULL == dict)
        goto fail;

    float screen_aspect = (float)width/(float)height;

        dict = strm_dict_set(dict, "video_dest_x", itoa((width - image_width) / 2, buffer, 10));
        if (NULL == dict)
            goto fail;

        width = height * image_aspect;

        dict = strm_dict_set(dict, "video_dest_w", itoa(width, buffer, 10));
        if (NULL == dict)
            goto fail;


    return dict;

fail:
    strm_dict_destroy(dict);
    return NULL;
}


int main(void) {

    int rc;
    int exit_application = 0;

    printf("DBG-1\n");

    // Screen variables
    screen_context_t    screen_context = 0;
    screen_window_t     screen_window = 0;

    int screen_size[2] = {0,0};

    // Renderer variables
    mmr_connection_t*     mmr_connection = 0;
    mmr_context_t*        mmr_context = 0;
    strm_dict_t*          dict = NULL;

    // I/O variables
    int                    video_device_output_id = -1;
    int                    audio_device_output_id = -1;

    printf("DBG-2\n");

        /*
        * Create the window used for video output.
        */
       if (screen_create_context(&screen_context, SCREEN_APPLICATION_CONTEXT) != 0) {
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       printf("DBG-3\n");

       if (screen_create_window(&screen_window, screen_context) != 0) {
           screen_destroy_context(screen_context);
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       printf("DBG-4\n");

       if (screen_create_window_group(screen_window, window_group_name) != 0) {
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       printf("DBG-5\n");

       int format = SCREEN_FORMAT_RGBA8888;
       if (screen_set_window_property_iv(screen_window, SCREEN_PROPERTY_FORMAT, &format) != 0) {
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }

       if(screen_set_window_property_cv(screen_window, SCREEN_PROPERTY_ID_STRING, 32, window_name)){
           perror("Set Window ID Error\n");
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }

       printf("DBG-6\n");

       int usage = SCREEN_USAGE_NATIVE;
       if (screen_set_window_property_iv(screen_window, SCREEN_PROPERTY_USAGE, &usage) != 0) {
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       printf("DBG-7\n");

       if (screen_create_window_buffers(screen_window, 1) != 0) {
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }

       printf("DBG-8\n");

       /*
        * Configure mm-renderer.
        */
       mmr_connection = mmr_connect(NULL);
       if (mmr_connection == NULL) {
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       printf("DBG-9\n");

       mmr_context = mmr_context_create(mmr_connection, video_context_name, 0, S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO);
       if (mmr_context == NULL) {
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       printf("DBG-11\n");
       /*
        * Configure video and audio output.
        */
       video_device_output_id = mmr_output_attach(mmr_context, video_device_url, "video");
       if (video_device_output_id == -1) {
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       printf("DBG-12\n");

       printf("DBG-13\n");
       // Get the render buffer
       screen_buffer_t temp_buffer[1];
       if (screen_get_window_property_pv( screen_window, SCREEN_PROPERTY_RENDER_BUFFERS, (void**)temp_buffer) != 0) {
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       printf("DBG-14\n");
       // Fill the buffer with a solid color (black)
       int fill_attributes[3] = {SCREEN_BLIT_COLOR, 0x0, SCREEN_BLIT_END};
       if (screen_fill(screen_context, temp_buffer[0], fill_attributes) != 0) {
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       printf("DBG-15\n");
       // Make the window visible
       if (screen_get_window_property_iv(screen_window, SCREEN_PROPERTY_SIZE, screen_size) != 0) {
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       printf("DBG-16\n");
       int temp_rectangle[4] = {0, 0, screen_size[0], screen_size[1]};
       if (screen_post_window(screen_window, temp_buffer[0], 1, temp_rectangle, 0) != 0) {
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       printf("DBG-17\n");
       // Prevent the backlight from going off
       int idle_mode = SCREEN_IDLE_MODE_KEEP_AWAKE;
       if (screen_set_window_property_iv(screen_window, SCREEN_PROPERTY_IDLE_MODE, &idle_mode) != 0) {
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       printf("DBG-18\n");
       // Build up the path where our bundled resource is.
       char cwd[PATH_MAX];
       char media_file[PATH_MAX];
       getcwd(cwd,PATH_MAX);

       rc = snprintf(media_file, PATH_MAX, "rtsp://10.42.0.1:8554/stream", cwd);    // Play video RTSP

       if ((rc == -1) || (rc >= PATH_MAX)) {
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       printf("DBG-19\n");
       /*
        * Start the playback.
        */
       if (mmr_input_attach(mmr_context, media_file, "track") != 0) {
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       printf("DBG-20\n");
       if (mmr_play(mmr_context) != 0) {
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }


       printf("DBG-21\n");
       /* Do some work to make the aspect ratio correct.
        */
       dict = calculate_rect(screen_size[0], screen_size[1]);
       if (NULL == dict) {
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       printf("DBG-22\n");
       if (mmr_output_parameters(mmr_context, video_device_output_id, dict) != 0) {
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }


       dict = NULL;

       sleep(60);

       if (mmr_stop(mmr_context) != 0) {
               return EXIT_FAILURE;
           }

           if (mmr_output_detach(mmr_context, audio_device_output_id) != 0) {
               return EXIT_FAILURE;
           }

           if (mmr_output_detach(mmr_context, video_device_output_id) != 0) {
               return EXIT_FAILURE;
           }

           if (mmr_context_destroy(mmr_context) != 0) {
               return EXIT_FAILURE;
           }

           mmr_context = 0;
           video_device_output_id = -1;
           audio_device_output_id = -1;

           mmr_disconnect(mmr_connection);
           mmr_connection = 0;


           if (screen_destroy_window(screen_window) != 0) {
               return EXIT_FAILURE;
           }

           if (screen_destroy_context(screen_context) != 0) {
               return EXIT_FAILURE;
           }

           screen_context = 0;
           screen_window = 0;

           return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

First image after start play RTSP video:


I tried buffering the incoming RTSP data for 2 seconds and playing it, but it seems too complicated and I couldn't do it. I couldn't quite figure out if there was a problem with the stream.
How can I fix this issue?
